# Find the constraints which guarantee that 6 planes in 3D space form a convex box containing the origin?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, convex-geometry, computational-geometry, solid-geometry

I ever asked a question to find the constraints which ensure 4 lines in 2D space form a convex quadrilateral; see [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4525127/formulate-constraints-such-that-the-intersection-area-of-4-half-planes-formed-b) and it has been solved by @YNK [author](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/587353/ynk) perfectly.

Now I hope to extend it and came across a **new challenge**. We learned that the equation of a plane not passing through the origin in 3D space can be $\{ax + by + cz - 1 = 0: a,b,c \in \mathbb{R} \land  a^2+b^2+c^2 \ne 0 \}$. A plane always cuts the whole 3D space into two half-spaces, and this equation ensures that any point in the same half-space as the origin $(0,0,0)$ always makes the inequality $ax+by+cz−1<0$ hold.

Given 6 planes not passing through the origin, and consider a set $S$ formed by these planes: $$S := \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: \bigwedge_{m=1}^6 a_mx + b_my +c_mz - 1 \le 0 \}.$$ **My question is,** which constraints on the coefficients $a_m, b_m, c_m, m=1,...,6$ of these 6 planes can guarantee that the set $S$ is a convex box (Of course the origin is in $S$ because $a_m0 + b_m0 +c_m0 - 1 =-1 < 0$. Note that in some cases, 6 planes do form a box but do not contain the origin,  and therefore the box is not the set $S$ that we want.).

I think we first need to ensure that there are 8 intersection points serving as 8 vertices of the box, each point met by 3 planes. And then,....

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "box" here? It only takes four planes to enclose a region. If that tetrahedron falls entirely on the underside of the other two planes, it has a non-empty convex set $S$. Do this tetrahedron still count? or is it excluded since two of the planes do not form any part of the border of $S$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I know what you mean, just like in 2D space, the set formed by 4 lines can be a triangle not a quadrilateral. Here the box means a polytope with 6 faces, like a cube ...... But I am also very happy if you can give constraints to guarantee that the convex set $S$ is bounded, no matter whether it is a tetrahedron or a box. This is an open problem, and what I really want is to find conditions to guarantee $S$ is bounded set. Of course, that would also be good if we can guarantee that $S$ is both bounded and has exactly 6 faces.